# R wrong result with for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have below code

```
n=c('a','b','c')
one=c('a','c')
two=c('b','a')
three=data.frame(one, two)
m=matrix(0,3,2)
for (i in length(n) ) {
   m[i,]=t(1*(n[i]==three[,1])-1*(n[i]==three[,2]))
}

t(1*(n[1]==three[,1])-1*(n[1]==three[,2]))
t(1*(n[2]==three[,1])-1*(n[2]==three[,2]))
t(1*(n[3]==three[,1])-1*(n[3]==three[,2]))
```

why the output of m matrix and output of last 3 lines is different? is there any  efficient way to do this?

Comment: `i in 1:length(n)` or `i in seq(length = n)`

Comment: is there a better way to do this using apply functions?

Comment: Yes, there is.  Please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

Because you want

```
for (i in seq_along(n)) {
```

Comment: is there a better way to do this using apply functions?

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked if there was a better way to do this with an `apply` function, here you go.  The result from `do.call(rbind, ...)` is "naturally" coerced to a matrix, so there is no need to define the matrix `m` beforehand.

I'm not understanding the logic behind multiplying by 1, so I left it out.  It will still work if you need it.

```
> n <- c('a','b','c')
> three <- data.frame(one = c("a", "c"), two = c("b", "a"))
> m <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(n), function(i){
+     t((n[i] == three[,1]) - (n[i] == three[,2]))
+ }))
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   -1
[2,]   -1    0
[3,]    0    1
```